# xibs in horizontal scrollview in swift

Tags: swift, swift3

my requirement is i have horizontal scroll view in second half of the screen in that second half i am loading xib as a swipe layout  and my first half i have bar code reader.[click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTgLe.png)

if user  user click on scan button camera will and it will scan the bar code and get output if user in the first view in scroll then scaned value should be in first xibs textview and the code is

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import AVFoundation
class sgstockallocationserialnumberViewController:    SGBaseViewController,UIScrollViewDelegate,AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {



@IBOutlet weak var serialnumberprocessezsorcancelview: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var txtseialnumbers: UITextView!

@IBOutlet weak var clientview: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var scroll_horizontal: UIScrollView!

@IBOutlet weak var serialinternalview: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var cameraview: UIView!



var featureArray = [Dictionary<String,String>]()
var stockList: [Parameters] = []
var captureSession: AVCaptureSession!
var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
var output = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
var orderlines: sgpurchaseorderorderlinewithmsg?
var arrayofcode:[String] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

       // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    serialnumberprocessezsorcancelview.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    serialnumberprocessezsorcancelview.layer.shadowColor =   UIColor.gray.cgColor
    serialnumberprocessezsorcancelview.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2, height: 2)
    serialnumberprocessezsorcancelview.layer.shadowRadius = 5
    serialnumberprocessezsorcancelview.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    clientview.layer.cornerRadius = 5


           print(scroll_horizontal.contentSize)
    scroll_horizontal.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false

    scroll_horizontal.delegate = self
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(sgstockallocationserialnumberViewController.dismissKeyboard))

    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    if SGManager.sharedManager.getorderlines()?.data != nil{


        let modeldata =  SGManager.sharedManager.getorderlines()
        self.orderlines = modeldata


        for i in 0...(orderlines?.data.count)! - 1 {

         let cell_details =
                ["title":self.orderlines?.data[i].productName,"Quantity":String(describing:self.orderlines!.data[i].quantity!)] as [String : Any]
        featureArray.append(cell_details as! [String : String])
              }
              let cell_details = ["title":"Miscellaneous","Quantity":""]
               featureArray.append(cell_details )
    }




       }
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    scroll_horizontal.isPagingEnabled = true
    scroll_horizontal.contentSize = CGSize(width:     self.serialinternalview.frame.size.width * CGFloat(featureArray.count), height: 188)

    self.loadFeatures()
      }
      override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
       super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()


           }
func dismissKeyboard() {

    view.endEditing(true)

}

func loadFeatures() {

    for (index, feature) in featureArray.enumerated() {
        if let featureView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Feature", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? FeatureView {
            featureView.seraialnumbertextareaview.layer.borderColor = UIColor.UIColorFromRGB(fromHex: 0xD6D6D6).cgColor
                           featureView.seraialnumbertextareaview.layer.borderWidth = 1
            featureView.internalview_xib.layer.borderColor = UIColor.UIColorFromRGB(fromHex: 0xD6D6D6).cgColor
            featureView.internalview_xib.layer.borderWidth = 1
            featureView.internalview_xib.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            featureView.internalview_xib.layer.masksToBounds = true

            featureView.seraialnumbertextareaview.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            featureView.seraialnumbertextareaview.layer.masksToBounds = true

            featureView.lblnetworkname.text = feature["title"]
           featureView.lblquantity_xib.text = feature["Quantity"]
            var textview_ = ""





           featureView.tag = index



            scroll_horizontal.addSubview(featureView)
            featureView.frame.size.width = self.serialinternalview.frame.width
            featureView.frame.origin.x = CGFloat(index) * self.serialinternalview.frame.size.width
       print(featureView.frame.origin.x)
            print(self.serialinternalview.bounds.size.width)

        }

    }


}

func buyFeature (sender:UIButton) {
    print("The user wants to buy feature \(sender.tag)")
}


func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
  let page = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width
   //     print(Int(page))
 //   featurePageControl.currentPage = Int(page)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



@IBAction func process(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if txtseialnumbers.text != ""{
        getnewpurchaseorderfiltermanufacturer()

    }
    else {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "No serial numbers detected", message:"add the serial numbers", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}

@IBAction func cancel(_ sender: UIButton) {
}


func getnewpurchaseorderfiltermanufacturer(){
    stockList.removeAll()
    let stocklistintrernal : Parameters = [
        "productid"            :0,
        "productCategoryId"        : 1,   "productParameterValue": txtseialnumbers.text]
    print(txtseialnumbers.text)
    stockList.append(stocklistintrernal)
     UserDefaults.standard.setValue(txtseialnumbers.text, forKey: "serialnumbers")
      let clientid_stockallocation =  UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "clientidfromstockallocation") 
      let params: [String : Any] = ["productParameterValue" :stockList,"isCommit":"False","toClientId":clientid_stockallocation]
                SGWebServices.sharedWebServices.stockalloction(params:params) { (error, response) in
        if (error == nil) {
            var purchaseordermanufacturer:sgstockallocationwhenserialnumberpassed?
            purchaseordermanufacturer = response

         //   print(purchaseordermanufacturer?.message)
            if purchaseordermanufacturer?.message == "Success"
            {


                let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
                let encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: response!)
                userDefaults.set(encodedData, forKey: "summary")
                userDefaults.synchronize()



                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SGStockallocationsummaryViewController")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(self.stockList, forKey: "stoclist")
                self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)


            }
            else
            {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: purchaseordermanufacturer?.message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))

                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)



            }
           // print("success")

            }
        else{
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "!", message: String(describing: error), preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))

            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)



            }}}






override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if (captureSession?.isRunning == false) {
        captureSession.startRunning();
    }
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    if (captureSession?.isRunning == true) {
        captureSession.stopRunning();
    }
}



@IBAction func scanstarted(_ sender: UIButton) {


   barcodereaderon()


}

@IBAction func scanstop(_ sender: UIButton) {
    stopsession()

    print(arrayofcode.count)
}


func  barcodereaderon(){




   // view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

    let videoCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)
    let videoInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput

    do {
        videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoCaptureDevice)
    } catch {
        return
    }

    if (captureSession.canAddInput(videoInput)) {
        captureSession.addInput(videoInput)
    } else {
        failed();
        return;
    }

    let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()

    if (captureSession.canAddOutput(metadataOutput)) {
        captureSession.addOutput(metadataOutput)

        metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)

        metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes =    [AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code,
                                                 AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code,
                                                 AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code,
                                                 AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode,
                                                 AVMetadataObjectTypeUPCECode,
                                                 AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code,
                                                 AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Mod43Code,
                                                 AVMetadataObjectTypeCode93Code,
                                                 AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code,
                                                 AVMetadataObjectTypeAztecCode]



    } else {
        failed()
        return
    }

    previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession);
    previewLayer.frame = cameraview.layer.bounds;
    previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;

    cameraview.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
    captureSession.startRunning();




}
func stopsession(){

captureSession.stopRunning()
cameraview.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
previewLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()

}
func failed() {
    let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Scanning not supported", message: "Your device does not support scanning a code from an item. Please use a device with a camera.", preferredStyle: .alert)
    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
    present(ac, animated: true)
    captureSession = nil
}

func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [Any]!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
   //  captureSession.stopRunning()

    if let metadataObject = metadataObjects.first {
        let readableObject = metadataObject as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject;

        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
        //  dismiss(animated: true)
        found(code: readableObject.stringValue);
    }


}

         func found(code: String) {
    if arrayofcode.contains(code) {

    }
    else{

         let page = scroll_horizontal.contentOffset.x / scroll_horizontal.frame.size.width
        print(page)
        var featureView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Feature", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? FeatureView
     //   featureView?.tag = Int(page)



      //  var tmpButton = featureView?.viewWithTag(Int(page)) as? tea
        print(Int(page))
         featureView = featureView?.viewWithTag(Int(page)) as! FeatureView?
       featureView?.textarea_xib.text = code
          print(featureView?.textarea_xib.text!)
        arrayofcode.append(code)
        var barcodeinarraay:[String] = []
          arrayofcode.append(code)














    }

        //    UserDefaults.standard.set(code, forKey: "code")
         //  UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

        print(code)
      //  arrayofcode.append(code)
   // let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
   // let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "screenViewController")
//    self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    //


}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}

       override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .portrait
}
```

}

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: my question is i am getting scanned values but i am unable to bind to correspoinding  nib view

Comment: can u help me..